# Python decorator to limit number of calls

Tags: python, decorator

I would like to write a decorator that limits the number of calls to the wrapped function. Say, if I want the wrapped function to be called maximum 10 times, the decorator should execute that function the first 10 times, then it should return `None` instead.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
from functools import wraps


def max_calls(num):
     """Decorator which allows its wrapped function to be called `num` times"""

     def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            calls = getattr(wrapper, 'calls', 0)
            calls += 1

            if calls == num:
                return None

            setattr(wrapper, 'calls', calls)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        setattr(wrapper, 'calls', 0)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

However, this count calls properly, returns `None` when the limit is reached, but...it doesn't reset between program runs. That is, if I execute the program once, the counter reaches 5, and then re-execute the program, it continues from 5. What do I need to change so that the decorator works properly?

Comment: On my machine, the counter resets as expected when I run the script a second time. How are you executing your script? I'm guessing you're not doing `python myscript.py` from the command line.

Comment: `That is, if I execute the program once, the counter reaches 5, and then re-execute the program, it continues from 5` .. can you please explain how you are executing the program?

Comment: are you running inside the python interpreter ?

Comment: I have a Flask application and in a view I start executing a function decorated with the above decorator. Inside this function there are other calls to the same function; the idea I want to achieve is to let only say, 10 times, the wrapped function to be called, then return `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you maintain just one set of call counts. But that means each Flask request shares call counts with all the other requests. What you need to do is to maintain a separate set of call counts for each Flask request.

From reading the [API documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/) it looks as though the way to make this work is to carry out these three steps:

1. Make a subclass of [`flask.Request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#incoming-request-data) that can store your function call counts:

   ```
   import collections
   import flask

   class MyRequest(flask.Request):
       """A subclass of Request that maintains function call counts."""
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(MyRequest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.call_counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
   ```
2. Set [`request_class`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.request_class) to your subclass when you initialize your application:

   ```
   app = flask.Flask(__name__, request_class=MyRequest, ...)
   ```
3. Rewrite your decorator to store its counts in the global [`flask.request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.request) object:

   ```
   import functools

   def max_calls(num, default=None):
       """Decorator which allows its wrapped function to be called at most `num`
       times per Flask request, but which then returns `default`.

       """
       def decorator(func):
           @functools.wraps(func)
           def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
               if flask.request.call_counts[func] == num:
                   return default
               flask.request.call_counts[func] += 1
               return func(*args, **kwargs)
           return wrapper
       return decorator
   ```

But having written that, it would be remiss for me not to point out that your question seems very strange. Why do you want to restrict the number of times a function can be called by a Flask request? Are you trying to do some kind of rate limiting? It seems likely that whatever you want to do can be done better using some other approach.

Comment: It sounds pretty strange, but it's the best solution for my problem: the wrapped function makes Soundcloud API calls to retrieve a song by given search term (with search terms changing from one call to another). If searching fails more then 10 times, my function should return `None` instead of infinitely trying to search the API with different search terms. Actually, it's not quite infinite, because at some time it will eventually return something, but this limit acts more as a timeout, maintaining the request time at a reasonable limit.